# How do I pass on the user input to a other textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have got two input field. Don't know how to pass on the user input from the first to the second, so that it simultaneously will add the same text. Can somebody help me out?

```
<h1>1. How should the perfect world look like?</h1>
<input id="perfectworld" class="" name="perfectworld_des" type="text" placeholder="How should the perfect world look like?" size="65" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function select_all()
{
var text_val=eval("document.form1.type");
text_val.focus();
text_val.select();
}
</script>
<form name=form1 method=post action=''''>
<textarea name=type rows=3 cols=35 onClick="select_all();">In a perfect world (Input from frist form goes here) @TwitterName #HASHTAG</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you use plan JavaScript or did you include JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You would just use an **keyup** event on your input field. When the event triggers, replace the part of your text with the value given and insert that new text in the textarea. Using jQuery I can give you a little example:

```
var myinput = $('#perfectworld');
var mytext = $('#mytext');
var giventext = 'In a perfect world #placeholder# @TwitterName #HASHTAG';
myinput.keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var newtext =  giventext.replace('#placeholder#', value);
    mytext.html(newtext);
});
```

Have a look at the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3by2a5v1/

Comment: Thank you very much. But it somehow wont work out. I had to change the input to a textarea. Would you mind having a look at it? http://www.idsnewcastle.org/perfectworld/